# Change Cell back ground color based on it's value

Tags: html, sql, formatting

This is related to HTML coding. I've to prepare a report by getting data from a SQL table. I've developed a code for this and is works well. But to increase the user experience, I want to change the cell background color (not row) based on cell value. In the below code, "Status" column will have values Completed\In Progress\Error\Unknown. Based on these values I want to change the cell background color as Green\Orange\Red\Gray.

```
set nocount on 
DECLARE @Style NVARCHAR(MAX)= '';
DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX)= '';
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SET @Style += +N'<style type="text/css">' + N'.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:10px;border-color:#aaa;}'
+ N'.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:5px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#333;}' 
+N'tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#546415;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:#fff;}'
+ N'.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:6px 6px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#fff;background-color:#614596;}'
+ N'.tg .tg-9ajh{font-weight:bold;background-color:#614596}' + N'.tg .tg-hgcj{font-weight:bold;text-align:center}'
+ N'</style>';

SELECT @Table = @Table +
'<td>' + ProductID + '</td>' +
'<td>' + ProductName+ '</td>' +
'<td>' + OrderedBy+ '</td>' +
'<td align=center>' + Status+ '</td>' +
'<td>' + Location+ '</td>' +
'</tr>'
FROM DBTable

SET @tableHTML += @Style + @tableHTML + N'<H2><font color="DIMGRAY">Status Report'+'</H2>' 
+ N'<table class="tg">' 
+ N'<tr bgcolor=#ccc>' 
+ N'<th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="1">ProductID</th>' 
+ N'<th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="1">ProductName</th>'
+ N'<th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="1">OrderedBy</th>'
+ N'<th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="1">Status</th>'
+ N'<th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="1" >Location</th>'
```

After googling, I found something like below. But since I'm being beginner in html, I unable to integrate below code to the above to accomplish my task. Can someone help me how to combine these codes so that I'll get data output as shown below.

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');

   for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
    if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) > 5){
        cells[i].className = 'red';
    }
    else if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) < -5){
       cells[i].className = 'green';
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "*dba.se is **not** the right place to ask questions about .. Client-side programming*"

Comment: You probably shouldn't be generating your HTML in the query anyway

Comment: Thank Tom, but we are following the same for most of our reports. So any help on this will greatly help me.